# Converting raw log file data into CSV file

Tags: ruby, regex, csv

I have some raw data I scraped from a log file, which currently reads as:

```
"   80:  0.20%:  2/Jan/14 21:01: /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-07-15-2013.mp3", 
"   71:  0.16%:  14/Jan/14 12:18: /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-11-04-2013.mp3", 
"   67:  0.17%:  2/Jan/14 23:44: /site/podcasts/audio/podcast-3-21-2011.mp3", 
"   67:  0.15%:  15/Jan/14 09:25: /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-08-05-2013.mp3", 
"   64:  0.12%:  2/Jan/14 07:40: /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-11-04-2013-1.mp3",
```

I need to convert gather three pieces of information into data for an Excel spreadsheet -- the number before the intitial colon, the date, and the URL. So if I converted it into CSV, it would read as

```
80, 2/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-07-15-2013.mp3
71, 14/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-11-04-2013.mp3
67, 2/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/podcast-3-21-2011.mp3
```

And so on. However, I'm having trouble figuring out how to do that. I wrote some regexes to capture the right data, but I'm not sure how to convert those regexes into what I need.

There's this regex to get the first number: `^"\s{3}(\d+)`

And this regex could get the date: `(\d+\/\w{3}\/14)`

And this regex could get the URL: `(\/site\/podcasts\/audio\/.*\.mp3)`

However, I'm not sure how to take these regexes and convert them into the CSV I need. Any ideas?

Comment: Does your log file actually have those quotes and commas in it?

Comment: Hi @sawa, yes, it's an array (I removed the brackets). I noticed that before you had posted what seemed like an elegant solution to this problem that's no longer there -- unfortunately, I haven't been able to look into testing it before now. Is there a reason why it's been deleted?

Comment: And @jkillian, no, log the file does not. The data above is what I scraped from the log file with my Ruby script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally wouldn't use regular expressions:

```
output = ''
File.open("path/to/log", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    num, percent, date, time, url = line.split(/\s+/)
    num = num[0..-2]  # removes the colon from the end of the number
    output << "#{num}, #{date}, #{url}\n"
  end
end

# do whatever you want with the result
puts output
```

And this prints:

```
80, 2/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-07-15-2013.mp3
71, 14/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-11-04-2013.mp3
67, 2/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/podcast-3-21-2011.mp3
67, 15/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-08-05-2013.mp3
64, 2/Jan/14, /site/podcasts/audio/2013/podcast-11-04-2013-1.mp3
```

There are shorter, more clever ways to do this, but I like this way because it's readable and clear.

Comment: Hi @jkillian, this seems like an excellent solution -- thank you. However, I am getting outputs in the format of `, 0.20%:, 21:01:` and so on -- so it's pulling the wrong pieces of data from each line. I'm trying to figure it out, but do you have an idea of why?

Comment: @CodeBiker Your log format might be a little different that what I expected... Add in `puts line` above the line with `split` and give me an example of what a line looks like

Comment: This seems to work, although I removed the part about the colon because sometimes that number has more than two digits: `File.open("log", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    quote, num, percent, date, time, url = line.split(/\s+/)
    output << "#{num}, #{date}, #{url}\n"
  end
end`

Comment: @CodeBiker Great, glad it worked for you! Actually though, it doesn't matter how many digits the number has: The `0..-2` range includes the characters from the first character (0) to the second to last character (-2) inclusive. So that line basically just trims off the last character no matter what.

Answer (score 1):

This puts your matches together and in capture groups that you can then later handle in Ruby. I'm unfamiliar with Ruby but I imagine you can concatenate the strings that the capture-groups return.

```
^"\s{3}(\d+)(?:[\s:]|\d\.\d\d%)*(\d+\/\w{3}\/14)[\s\d:]*(\/site\/podcasts\/audio\/.*\.mp3)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/KnlUu3ZgUOeyXOkW)

Comment: I marked the above jkillian's answer as correct because it got me to the right information. However, your regex is excellent -- the problem is that I'm not familiar enough with Ruby to know how to concatenate the strings from the capture groups.

Answer (score 1):

```
\s+(\d+):\s+.*?(\d+\/\w+\/\d+)\s+.*?(\/.*?)\".*
```

Try this.Please look at the demo.

http://regex101.com/r/cA4wE0/10